# Open .exe file using python and trying to pass parameter in the same python script

Tags: python-3.x, file

I'm trying to open a .exe file from Python and give it some instructions. Because I have thousands of models to run I need to automatize the process.

Here on Stackoverflow, I found several options that I tried. I am able to open .exe file but not able to fill the information in that and run the .exe. the place is always empty.  I'm writing one of these solutions. [I'm using Python3]:

```
import os
your_bat_file_address = r'"C:\D_drive\testing\SAR\1100_star3\exmple.bat"' # example
os.startfile(your_bat_file_address)
```

in the exmple.bat file

```
"C:/D_drive/tool/EXMPLE.exe"  --input1 "C:/D_drive/file/1st_file"  --input2 "C:/D_drive/file/2st_file"  --input3 "C:/D_drive/file/3st_file"
```

Comment: Have you tried to put everything in a single string? `"C:/D_drive/tool/EXMPLE.exe  --input1 C:/D_drive/file/1st_file ..."`

Comment: Yes, I tried to putting all in single string.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what problem you have. Can you please give more details?